# Iptables deny access to a specific IP address not working

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt

I'm not able to deny access to a specific IP address or deny access to a specific IP address range as well. My network environment is, I have one router which IP is (30.30.10.1) and second my hotspot are flashed to DD-WRT with IP (192.168.15.1). I needed to deny access to my hotspot user to my main router which IP is 30.30.10.1 or entire IP range. The command I saved in my firewall rules are list as below.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d 30.30.10.1 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 30.30.10.0/24 -j DROP
```

After I put this Iptables rules in my firewall I still able to get login into 30.30.10.1 webgui interface. What wrong with rules?

This is is `iptables -L` output.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1751  129K ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    1    84 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
 4085  444K ACCEPT     0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  vlan2  any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  br0    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  vlan2  any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       igmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
  344 49804 DROP       0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  any    tun1    anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  any    tun1    anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       0    --  any    any     192.168.182.0/24     30.30.15.0/24       
    0     0 DROP       0    --  any    any     192.168.182.0/24     30.30.15.0/24       
    0     0 ACCEPT     gre  --  any    vlan2   192.168.20.0/24      anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    vlan2   192.168.20.0/24      anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 
    0     0 lan2wan    0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    br0     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 TRIGGER    0    --  vlan2  br0     anywhere             anywhere            TRIGGER type:in match:0 relate:0 
    0     0 trigger_out  0    --  br0    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br0    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
    0     0 DROP       0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7319 packets, 3919K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_1 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_10 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_2 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_3 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_4 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_5 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_6 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_7 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_8 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain advgrp_9 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_10 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_2 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_3 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_4 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_5 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_6 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_7 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_8 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain grp_9 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain lan2wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 grp_1      0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
Chain logaccept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
Chain logdrop (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       0    --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
Chain logreject (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 
Chain trigger_out (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

This is `route -n` output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         30.30.15.1       0.0.0.0        UG    0      0        0 vlan2
30.30.15.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
172.16.1.1      172.16.1.46     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
172.16.1.46     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
172.16.254.0    172.16.1.46     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.87.0    172.16.1.46     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.182.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
```

Comment: Please post the output of 'iptables -L'

Comment: @Jarmund update the `iptables -L` output

Comment: There are a lot of interface specific rules with `-j ACCEPT` which come early in the queue, and might therefore override your additional `-j DROP` rules. Output of `route -n` is also needed to come up with something more specific.

Comment: @Jarmund updated `route -n` output.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a few months old and you may have found the solution but I wanted to give you an answer anyway.  Keep in mind that FORWARD rules apply to traffic passing *through* the router, not to or from the router itself.  To deny the traffic to your router, you need to create an INPUT rule naming the source network to drop:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.15.1-192.168.15.254 -j DROP
```